# Why do I have duplicate views in my Django rest framework urls.py?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to figure out how these endpoints work in django rest framework.

```py
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('api-auth', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('login', django_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='rest_framework/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout', django_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('register', views.UserCreate.as_view()),
    path('get_jwt_token', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('eos_verify_jwt_token', views.EOSVerifyJSONWebToken.as_view()),
]
```

I get the following patterns:

```
Using the URLconf defined in ugh_studios_webservices.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    api/ api-auth login/ [name='login']
    api/ api-auth logout/ [name='logout']
    api/ login [name='login']
    api/ logout [name='logout']
    api/ register
    api/ get_jwt_token
    api/ eos_verify_jwt_token
    admin/

The current path, api/api-auth, didn’t match any of these.
```

Why is there two login endpoints?

What I'm trying to do is have the following endpoints:

1. Login Endpoint
2. Logout Endpoint
3. User registration endpoint
4. JWT Token request + validation endpoints - this seems to work
5. Custom Validate user login (username + password) endpoint (response needs to be custom for integration with a separate application, it expects a certain response body)
6. Needs to be viewable in the browsable API https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/ - Why are none of my urls viewable except for the 'register' url?
7. Needs to be able to work with both an HTTP POST request (for validation/login) as well as an html template/view

I do not want to create duplicate code either, it seems like the rest_framework comes with some default views for logging in and out. All of the information I see on stack overflow recommends creating new view classes...etc. But why should I do that if the rest framework has given me some defaults that I simply do not have setup properly? It looks to me that the rest framework has everything I need already, but I do not have the urls.py setup correctly.

[image]

EDIT:

It seems like I get exactly what I want after changing my url patterns to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('register', views.UserCreate.as_view()),
    path('get_jwt_token', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('eos_verify_jwt_token', views.EOSVerifyJSONWebToken.as_view()),
]
```

However, I still need to figure out how to get the login to direct to the proper urls. It seems to redirect to /accounts/profile after logging in. I don't see a default html template for this though, so maybe this does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Going by your question - here is my explanation.

According to me, there are 3 login urls -

1. When we visit `localhost:8000/admin` to go to your admin panel it takes us to `http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/`
2. When we have rest framework installed and have included rest framework urls in our project.url file, something like `path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))`, when we check rest framework package, it has a urls.py file and contains a login url - `path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='rest_framework/login.html'), name='login')` and this LoginView comes from - `django/contrib/auth/views`

Now when you check this Class (LoginView) it has code something -

```
def get_success_url(self):
    url = self.get_redirect_url()
    return url or resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

and the value of login_redirect_url by default is `'/accounts/profile/'`, check  [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url). So you are redirected there, you can change the value in settings.

Now we can login directly to our api endpoints with url like `localhost:8000/api-auth/login/` (rest framework login) but when we try to login via a frontend client for eg a react application using token-based authentication we get CSRF error with this url.

3. Now to login with a token authentication system we need rest-auth. (this generates a token). we again have to include `path('rest-auth/', include('rest-auth.urls'))` in our project.urls, and have url `rest_auth/login`. and when you check the login class' serializer, there it uses allauth. so we have to get allauth too. Allauth enables us to manage login by username or email or by both and do more.